# QNAP TS-419U+ Raid5 not rebuilding

Tags: hard-drive, mdadm, raid-5, qnap

I replaced the hard disk number 1 on a QNAP TS-419U + with RAID5.
It is a hot-swapping replacement without turning off the machine.
It was smart of the new HD is good, but it was not added to Raid 5.

[Qnap software management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHoba.png)

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [raid0] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sdd3[3] sdc3[2] sdb3[1]
         5855836800 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [_UUU]

md4 : active raid1 sdd2[0] sdc2[2](S) sdb2[1]
         530048 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md13 : active raid1 sdd4[3] sdc4[2] sdb4[1]
         458880 blocks [4/3] [_UUU]
         bitmap: 18/57 pages [72KB], 4KB chunk

md9 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
         530048 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]
         bitmap: 1/65 pages [4KB], 4KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

I think that /dev/sda3 is missing

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda3
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sda3: No such device or address

# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 00.90.00
           UUID : 9e1b8560:8504bb63:f5ca59e1:4b21abb1
  Creation Time : Thu Jun  9 21:56:45 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1951945600 (1861.52 GiB 1998.79 GB)
     Array Size : 5855836800 (5584.56 GiB 5996.38 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri Dec  9 12:33:41 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 29c760bc - correct
         Events : 0.16604494

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3

   0     0       0        0        0      removed
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
   3     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3



 mdadm --examine /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 00.90.00
           UUID : 9e1b8560:8504bb63:f5ca59e1:4b21abb1
  Creation Time : Thu Jun  9 21:56:45 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1951945600 (1861.52 GiB 1998.79 GB)
     Array Size : 5855836800 (5584.56 GiB 5996.38 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri Dec  9 12:33:49 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 29c760e6 - correct
         Events : 0.16604502

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3

   0     0       0        0        0      removed
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
   3     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3


# mdadm --examine /dev/sdd3
/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 00.90.00
           UUID : 9e1b8560:8504bb63:f5ca59e1:4b21abb1
  Creation Time : Thu Jun  9 21:56:45 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1951945600 (1861.52 GiB 1998.79 GB)
     Array Size : 5855836800 (5584.56 GiB 5996.38 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri Dec  9 12:33:59 2016
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 29c7610e - correct
         Events : 0.16604508

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3

   0     0       0        0        0      removed
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
   3     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
```

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a partition on refurbished HD, I have replace the same partition scheme of the others drivers in RAID, by fdisk application, and rebooted the system.
Now the RAID is rebuilding the RAID 5